Why does a function app in Azure just stop working intermittently?
I have a function app in Azure that runs every minute , but occasionally it just stops and starts back up again.
It is on a Premium Plan.
Also should "Always On" in Configuration be on ?
This is a function app with a function that should run every minute , the function is not being triggered for some reason ?
Is there any way i can find out why it stops ?


Also should "Always On" in Configuration be on?

In Function App with Premium Plan, Always On is not available. It is available only in App Service Plan. Refer Article.

If you want to keep the function running, I suggest using App Service Plan as it gives the option of Always on in the function app=>configuration=>General Settings.


function app in Azure just stop working intermittently.


It could be due to the function app is running on a single instance and that instance is being restarted.
Scale out the function app to multiple instances to ensure that if one instance goes down, the other instances will continue to run your function app.
Use the dedicated storage account for your function app.

To see why the function is getting stopped, check the function logs in application insights.

Configure Application Insights in the Function App.



Navigate to the Application Insights of your function app=>Monitoring=>Logs:



I have created a timer trigger Azure function with premium plan and tested in my environment, it worked as expected:

